# System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. in .Net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A8ne.png)

I have asp.net core mvc application which we are migrating from MVC5 application and when I try to run the application after pull from azure repository, i getting this error in program.cs page itself and eventhough i googled with the same topic i didnt get relavant answer .
(Im  using visual studio 2022 - version 17.4.3)

could you pls give a exact solution for my problem
Thanks for ur assistance.

I need to resolve this issue and run the application

"System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.DropDownListBuilderBase`2' from assembly
'Kendo.Mvc, Version=2022.2.621.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4'.'"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My Core application needs "Demos - Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core R2 2022 SP1" this software on my Computer which i didnt installed. finally my colleague assisted me to solve this issue.
Thanks for your valueable time mates